# unit-test for BlackJack cardset

Tags: c#

How can I make a working unit test for this code:

- I want to test if there are 13 cards per color
- I want to test if there are 4 cards per value

CODE:

```
public class CardSet
{
    List<Card> cardset = new List<Card>();

    public CardSet()
    {
        AddCardsToSet();
    }

    public Card CreateCard(CardValue cardValue, CardSuit cardSuit)
    {

        return new Card(cardValue, cardSuit);
    }

    public void AddCardsToSet()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 13; z++)
            {
                cardset.Add(new Card((CardValue)z, (CardSuit)i));
            }
        }
    }

    public int ReturnSetSize()
    {
        return cardset.Count();
    }

    public List<Card> ReturnCardSetList()
    {
        return cardset;
    }

}
```

ENUM 1

```
public enum CardSuit
{
    Club,
    Spade,
    Heart,
    Diamond,
}
```

ENUM 2

```
public enum CardValue
{
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace,
}
```

NOTE: it is not that easy as you think...would be happy if some of you have solution for that.

Comment: What specific functionality are you looking to test?  What have you tried and how did it not work as expected?  Generally any unit test would follow the same three steps, (1) Arrange, (2) Act, (3) Assert.  For example, you can arrange by creating an instance of `CardSet`, act by calling `ReturnCardSetList`, and assert by comparing that returned value with what you expect.

Comment: this is a **very simple** LINQ query with GroupBy, All, Count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend at least writing your unit test scaffolding prior to my answering your question. Are you using MSUnit or some other test framework?

Below is an answer that should satisfy your criteria.
But, I will recommend the following:

1. split into separate test for suit count and value count
2. Add data driven parameter approach for VALUE or SUIT as parameter to run the same test method multiple times per parameter, so that in  any failure we can identify which VALUE or SUIT is failing the test.

Sample:

```
//given
var cardsPerSuitCount = 13;
var cardsPerValueCount = 4;

//when
var myDeck = new CardSet();
foreach (var suitGrp in myDeck.cardset.GroupBy(x => x.cardsuit))
{
  var suitCount = suitGrp.Count();
  //then
  //do your assert of cardsPerSuitCount vs suitCount here
}

foreach (var valueGrp in myDeck.cardset.GroupBy(x => x.cardvalue))
{
  var valueCount = valueGrp.Count();
  //then
  //do your assert of cardsPerValueCount vs valueCount here
}
```

Comment: Hello, I don't understand in the foreach part mydeck.cardset. Could you please explain it?

Comment: When I do a foreach of a myDeck.cardset.GroupBy(x => x.cardsuit),  I will get a "suitGrp" in each iteration. A "suitGrp" contains a collection of all cards matching one cardsuit. This means that the first iteration of "suitGrp" will contain all cards of Club, the second iteration contains all cards of Spade, etc...  This means that when we do a .Count(), we will get the sum of all cards of Club for example. And we can then compare it to check that it equals 13.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It worked :) Just had to add some using directives

Answer (score -1):

I am a blackjack fan.

The plan is;

1. Group all the cards by their suit and rank (I assume that the property names for these are `Suit` and `Value` in your code)
2. This will give us groups of distinct (suit,value) pairs each of which can have one or more cards under it. (having the same suit and value)
3. We expect all suits and values to fall in the range of our enums, so we check for this
4. And at the end, the test should succeed only if the number of groups is 52.

This guarantees that;

1. All the cards have suits between 0 and 3, and values between 0 and 12
2. There are no duplicate cards in the deck
3. There are exactly 52 cards in the deck

Using LinQ, this can be implemented as follows:

```
var deck = new CardSet();

var cardsInDeck = deck.ReturnCardSetList();

// preliminary simple check for null
Debug.Assert(cardsInDeck != null);

// preliminary simple check for card count
Debug.Assert(cardsInDeck.Count == 52);

// main assertion for the uniqueness and correctness of all the cards
Debug.Assert
(
    cardsInDeck
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Suit, x.Value })
        .Select(x =>
            (int)x.Key.Suit >= 0 && (int)x.Key.Suit <= 3 &&
            (int)x.Key.Value >= 0 && (int)x.Key.Value <= 12)
        .Count() == 52
);
```

Comment: @SirRufo no, that is not right. `Enumerable.Repeat(new Card(0, 0), 52).ToList()` would return a count of 1 because it will have only one group which would be (0,0) and 52 cards under it and would not satisfy the assertion because what it checks is not the number of cards but the number of groups.

Comment: @sir-rufo my response hasn't reached you I think

Comment: Yes, you are right ...